# Error in Google Apps Script when HTML form input field is empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

My `Google Apps Script` receives data from an `HTML` `form`, then sends an email confirmation to a customer. It gets the email address from `input type=email`, and if this input field is left blank, the script produces an error.

Here is the relevant part of my `Google Apps Script`:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var email = e.parameter.Email;
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Submission Received",
    body: "We have received your submission. Thank you.",
    htmlBody: HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(
      "Confirmation"
    ).getContent()
  });
}
```

How can I solve this so that when my referenced `form` `input` field is empty my script doesn’t produce an error?

(I know that one way to solve this is to put `required` attribite on the `input`, but the field is optional, so that doesn’t fix my problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't want to occur an error when `Email` is not inputted.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  if ("Email" in e.parameter && e.parameter.Email != "") { // Added
    var email = e.parameter.Email;
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Submission Received",
      body: "We have received your submission. Thank you.",
      htmlBody: HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(
        "Confirmation"
      ).getContent()
    });
  } else { // Added
    // If "Email" is not inputted, for example, you can do something here.
  }
}
```

- From your question, `Email` is inputted to the type of email. So I thought that it is not required to confirm whether the value of `Email` is the email.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.